# javascript solitare game, Getting javascript to check childNode values, is there an implied else?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm attempting my very first solitare game using javascript as the code. I found brainjar.com as a resource for this project, and so far so good. I've learned loads about javascript this way and I've managed primitive form of the game, albeit based on forms. Not neat-o, but somewhat functional.

Only now, I've gotten stuck.

Every time I attempt a "if else" check on the press of a button, the thing barfs. As in the game chooses to completely reset itself, or refuses to work at all. I figure I must be overlooking something somewhere.

The code would be a huge mess to post here, (me being a beginner and all, I know it's sloppy) but the link is here should anyone like to take a look at the source (warning, you may need to zoom out a bit on the display side, as I haven't optimized this thing yet) :

http://pluckzilla.com/game/clockgame.html

the function that the ugly green button near the top calls is this one:

---

```
//game play

//begin with 12

function twelve(){

hand12.combine(fingering);
fingering.addCard(hand12.deal());
display();


//and i need to figure out a way to make sure only the rank of queen is allowed in the stack.


}
```

---

Help?

---

### adding details as requested

```
//example on how to get the card objects to stack, and there are a lot of them. card   objects are in a separate js file

left = 0;
top  = 0;
el = document.getElementById("fingering");
while (el.firstChild != null)
el.removeChild(el.firstChild);
for (i = 0; i < fingering.cardCount(); i++) {
node = fingering.cards[i].createNode();
node.firstChild.style.visibility = "visible";
node.style.left = left + "em";
node.style.top  = top  + "em";
el.appendChild(node);
left += .20;
top  += 0.05;
}
```

---

odd thing is, it's almost as if there is an implied "else" going on when the if is set up like this:

```
function twelve(){
if (fingering.cards[0].rank==="10")
hand12.combine(fingering);
fingering.addCard(hand12.deal());


display();
```

the first card i tried was a 10, and the card exchange worked beautifully between both stacks, but the subsequent cards did not exchange fully, and soon enough hand 12 was empty, and fingering, which is only supposed to have one card max, had 5.

What's going on?

I see that brainjar declared a newArray to get the blackjack game to score a player's hand, but a score is not really needed in this game. (The game will end if there is 4 kings in the middle stack, but i haven't coded for that event just yet.)

Is there such thing as an implied else in javascript?

---

Shout out to MESSIAH there, he got my brain working somewhat, and allowed part of the problem to be solved. Now I just have to figure out how to get the card exchange to stop completely when the card is not the correct card.

---

added some code.. which works as intended...

```
function twelve(){
if (fingering.cards[0].rank!=="10")
alert ("nonono");

if (fingering.cards[0].rank==="10")
hand12.combine(fingering); 
fingering.addCard(hand12.deal());
display();
```

However, that annoying implied "else" effect is still happening on the ==="10" version, making the new code moot: running the last 2 lines regardless of what card is checked. Any ideas?

Comment: can you post some of your other code also?

Comment: sure, just added a bit.

Comment: Added more details to document, specifically the ones that have been frustrating me the most.

Comment: pinpoint the main area of your problem!!!not the entire code

Comment: It's that function twelve(). Why won't it let me have an "else" and work too? Is there such thing as an implied "else" in javascript? I know this script that i'm building upon is old, from about 2003, but it still works.

Comment: there are so may for loops inside your else condition...i dont think its a good way to code...and why are you creating so many instances..just create one instance..

Comment: Ok, where are you talking about? The stacking code, or the deal code?  Neither have an else, and they work. I never said i was great at coding, i just want to get this basic thing working.

Answer (score 0):

Aha!

make the two steps into one by declaring a separate function, and run it anyway.

```
 //begin with 12

 function twelve(){
 var card;
 if (fingering.cards[0].rank!=="10")
 alert ("nonono");

 if (fingering.cards[0].rank==="10")
 cardExchange();
 display();


 //and i need to figure out a way to make sure only the rank of queen is allowed in the stack.


 }
 function cardExchange(){
 hand12.combine(fingering); 
 fingering.addCard(hand12.deal());
 }
```